# Verification: matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

T(x,y)=(2x-y,3x-y)

with respect to basis (1,0), and (0,1) Now M(T)=
        $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      2&3&x\\
      -1&-1&y
    \end{array}
\right] $$

gives  \begin{pmatrix}
        2x+3y \\
        -x-y \\
      \end{pmatrix}

so this cannot be the transformation matrix

The correct one is

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      2&-1&x\\
      3&-1&y
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Also, how do I find the matrix transformation of (x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z) for basis (1,0) and (0,1). So we are going from 3 dimensions to 2. So my matrix should have 2 rows and 2 columns right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider linear map ${\sf T}:{\sf R}^3\rightarrow {\sf R}^2$ defined by
${\sf T}(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z)$, we always use the two bases for the domain and the co-domain, to obtain a matrix representation. 
For example, use the standard ordered bases for ${\sf R}^3$ and ${\sf R}^2$, respectively. That is, 
$$\beta=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\gamma=\{\bar{e}_1,\bar{e}_2\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
and do the following works:
\begin{align*}
{\sf T}(e_1)
&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=1\cdot\bar{e}_1+0\cdot\bar{e}_2,\\
{\sf T}(e_2)
&=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=1\cdot\bar{e}_1+1\cdot\bar{e}_2,\\
{\sf T}(e_3)
&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=0\cdot\bar{e}_1+1\cdot\bar{e}_2.
\end{align*}
Hence we get the matrix representation of ${\sf T}$ with respect to $\beta$ and $\gamma$ as below:
$$[{\sf T}]_\beta^\gamma=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: And what about the first one? Did I get that right?

Comment: @anna_xox Yes, but I emphasize again that the matrix representation of the given transformation is determined by the two bases.